# Cannot read property 'RecaptchaVerifier' of undefined in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send message using `signInWithPhoneNumber` from firebase but I am getting following error on implementing , I also imported firebase  still same issue.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export class TabPage implements OnInit{
  code: string = '+91';
  spin: boolean = false;
  otpSent:boolean = false;


  recaptchaverifier;
  confirmationResult: firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult;
  phoneNumber: string;
ngOnInit(){
    this.recaptchaverifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
    this.sendOTP();
  }

sendOTP(){
    var phNo = this.code+'******';

    this.spin = true;
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phNo,this.recaptchaverifier).then(result=>{
      this.phoneNumber = phNo;
      this.otpSent = true;
      this.confirmationResult = result;
      this.spin = false;
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(err=>{
      this.spin = false;
      alert(err);
    });
  }
}
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only importing the core Firebase SDK. In order to use Firebase Authentication, you also need to import that SDK by adding:

```
import 'firebase/auth';
```